# WinForms AutoSave To Database (vs. Save Button)

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I'm writing a WinForms (C#) using Entity Framework. application

Currently, I have a big fancy Save Button on my form that works just as you'd hope and expect it to.

I have been asked to change the application to save automatically as the the user changes each field.

I know I can do this by adding code to the Value_Changed event in each of my controls. But is there an easier way? There are a large number of controls on this form. Some way to overload the OnChange event for multiple control types (Text, DropDown, CheckBox, RadioButton)?

Comment: `INotifyPropertyChanged` was my first thought immediately followed by wow that is going to slow everything down. I guess save could be done on navigation and suspension, but that removes the save button  and is not saving after each field. Do you know why they want it to save after each field change?

Comment: This is a rather broad question.

Comment: You could ask whether it would be sufficient or not to save the data when the form has become inactive or is closed. Would make it far easier. I don't know why this requirement came up but it doesn't hurt to suggest. Or save it every x seconds/minutes in  addition to calling save when the form is closed.

Comment: Oh! that is bad, clients always had a delusional ideas. Hope you can explain to them the disadvantages and make them accept the button save purposes.

Answer (score 0):

In the form's constructor, loop through all of its child controls (this.Controls) recursively and add the (same) callback method to the ValueChanged event for each of them. That will associate it with each control on the form regardless of any changes to the form in the future.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
     public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
            {
                c.Validated += C_Validated;
            }
        }

        private void C_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        Debug.Print($"{sender.GetType().FullName} had Validated event called");
        }
    }
}
```